# Windows Forms Application - Error creating window handle

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Code in Form1.cs: In which, I **hid Form1.cs** then **showed Form2.cs**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide(); 
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
}
```

Code in Form2.cs: In which, I **hid Form2.cs** and tried to **show Form1.cs** again then the **Error creating window handle** appeared on runtime.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    f1.Show();
}
```

Comment: You are creating a *new* instance of Form1.  Which gets the Form1_Load event to fire again.  Which creates a new instance of Form2 so the Form2_Load event fires again.  Which creates a new instance of Form1 so the Form1_Load event fires again.  Which creates a new instance of Form2 so the Form2_Load event fires again   Which ....  repeat ... repeat ... Kaboom!

Comment: Thanks, you're like a profiler hahaha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When loading Form1, you show a *new, additional* Form2.
- When loading Form2, you show a *new, additional* Form1.

This is a circle. It's creating new Forms as fast as it gets, each Form1 a Form2 and each Form2 a new Form1 and then it starts the circle again until there is no more window Handles left to create new windows.

I'm not really sure what you *want* to do, but this is not the way to do it. Describe what you want to do and maybe we can help.

Comment: I'm creating an application that will go to the "MainForm" then eventually will load/check the "LicenseForm"; if License is successful, I will comeback to show the "Mainform" and hid the License form. Well, thanks, I now got the idea.